# Faster approach to enter rows in a time table in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, performance

I need to fill a time table to use it for joining the data in reporting services.
Generally I do this with this code:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tqTimeTable

DECLARE @CNT int
DECLARE @DATE datetime
DECLARE @END int

SET @CNT  = 1
SET @DATE = 25567 -- 01.01.1970
SET @END  = 20000 -- + 20k days => years 2024

WHILE(@CNT < @END)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tqTimeTable (Tag, Monat, Jahr)
  VALUES (DATEADD(day,@CNT,@DATE), MONTH(DATEADD(day,@CNT,@DATE)), YEAR(DATEADD(day,@CNT,@DATE)))
  SET @CNT = @CNT + 1
END;
```

But this takes a while (on my test system around 2 minutes) so I hope someone had the same issue and solved it better then me. 
As I fire this statement from a .NET connection I need a faster solution or if there isn't one to raise the timeout of my connection.

Comment: Weird. On my system this takes around 5 seconds. And on SQLFiddle about 13s: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5965b/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adding

```
BEGIN TRAN
WHILE(@CNT < @END)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tqTimeTable (Tag, Monat, Jahr)
  VALUES (DATEADD(day,@CNT,@DATE), MONTH(DATEADD(day,@CNT,@DATE)), YEAR(DATEADD(day,@CNT,@DATE)))
  SET @CNT = @CNT + 1
END;
COMMIT
```

will speed it up as you are doing many individual commits (that all require the log to be written to disc). I would do a set based insert in a single statement though.

```
   WITH E1(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    )                                       -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
    , E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)   -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
    , E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)   -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
    , E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b)   -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
    , NUMS(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) FROM  E8)
INSERT INTO tqTimeTable
            (Tag,
             Monat,
             Jahr)
SELECT DATEADD(day, N, @DATE),
       MONTH(DATEADD(day, N, @DATE)),
       YEAR(DATEADD(day, N, @DATE))
FROM   NUMS
WHERE  N <= 20000
```

Comment: The transaction was it, works in 1 second now...Your set based statement popup an error here (wrong syntax close to WITH), but the time is more then acceptable fast now, so no more need to solve this...

Comment: @YvesR - If it is preceded by any other statements they need to be terminated with a semicolon.#

Comment: Yes, it works now with correct ; speration. But honestly, this query is to much rocket science for me :) Do not understand at all how it works.